# Adding Count For each multiple conditions loop and returning total records XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="z">0</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="x">0</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count(wd:Supplier_Invoice_Line_group)>1">
        <xsl:for-each select="wd:Supplier_Invoice_Line_group">
          <xsl:value-of select="$z =$z+1 "/>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$x =$x+1 "/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
<xsl:value-of select="$x+$z"/>
```

I'm not getting any results for the above conditions. I'm trying to declare 2 variables for 2 different loops. Then adding those records to get total counts. Appreciate if anyone can guide me.

Comment: Please edit your post for a [mcve]. A snippet of code is not helpful for us. We cannot test your code without a sample XML, full XSLT, and desired result.

Comment: Once a variable has been given a value, the value cannot subsequently be changed. If you add a minimal reproducible example, like @Parfait suggested, we can offer alternatives to accomplish what you need. (xsl:accumulator, xsl:number, count(), position(), etc.)

Comment: And please say which version of XSLT you are using. Like many problems, this one is much easier with XSLT 2.0 or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems where you have `<xsl:value-of select="$x+$z"/>` you just could use `<xsl:value-of select="sum((wd:Report_Entry/count(wd:Supplier_Invoice_Line_group), count(wd:Report_Entry[not(wd:Supplier_Invoice_Line_group)])))"/>`. That assumes XSLT 2 or later.